# PhpStorm code reformatter treatment of semi-colons

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

I write:

```
$loggedInUser = new User();
$loggedInUser
    ->setFirstName("John")
    ->setLastName("Doe")
    ->setAge(42)
;
```

When I invoke PhpStorm's code reformatter, it moves the `;` character up, and gives:

```
$loggedInUser = new User();
$loggedInUser
    ->setFirstName("John")
    ->setLastName("Doe")
    ->setAge(42);
```

Is there a way to make it use the first style, with the semi-colon in its own line, or at least not re-format it?

I looked through all the code-style settings and couldn't find anything that looked relevant, but maybe I missed some style definition, or a separate setting.

I am aware of the `// @formatter:off` technique, but I don't want to litter my code with it.

Comment: Have you checked `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces ---> Chained method calls | Place ';' on new line` option?

Comment: It may still not work when it's used in `return` statement though (e.g https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34152)

Comment: Wow!! You're good! If you post it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that `Chained method calls | Place ';' on new line` option is checked:

1. Settings / Preferences
2. Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces

[image]

**NOTE:** Currently it does not seem to work properly when such chaining is used in `return` statement (watch [WI-34152](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34152) ticket for that).